# Encoding filenames with encfsctl which begin with a "-"

Tags: linux, perl, encryption

I got a problem with encfsctl encoding a filename starting with a "-" via commandline.
Apparently encfsctl considers the filename as an option.

Example

```
encfsctl encode --extpass="cat cryptkey" /rootdir/ "-123"
```

Output:

```
encode: invalid option -- '1'
16:49:51 (encfsctl.cpp:250) getopt error: 63
encode: invalid option -- '2'
16:49:51 (encfsctl.cpp:250) getopt error: 63
encode: invalid option -- '3'
16:49:51 (encfsctl.cpp:250) getopt error: 63
```

After this encfsctl waits for input and does not terminate.
On the bash I could enter now "-123" to get the encoded output.
However I need to call the command from a more complex perl script.

Anyone got an idea how to fix that?

Comment: The conventional way that Linux command-line utilities deal with this issue is to allow a field of just two hyphens `--` to indicate that there are no more options in the command. I can't see any reference to this in the documentation for `encfsctl`, but have you tried `encfsctl encode --extpass="cat cryptkey" -- /rootdir/ -123`? If it is a Perl program then this will certainly work

Comment: Another workaround is to prepend a directory to the filename, most trivially as `./-123`

Comment: thank you @Borodin, this works. i'd mark that as my answer, but it seems i can't mark comments as answers.